# Click event not firing in polymer paper-icon-button

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have the following page defined

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Practice List</title>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/styles.css" />
    <!-- google fonts definitions -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
</head>
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <dom-module id="app">
        <template>
            <paper-drawer-panel>
                <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
                    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
                        <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                        <span class="flex"></span>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="srchandler"></paper-icon-button>
                        <input type="text" id="searchText" style="width:200px; background:#3180ed;line-height:20px;border:solid 1px #4d90eb; border-radius:6px; padding:3px;color:#fff;" />
                        <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name ident">Practice List</div>
                    </paper-toolbar>
                </paper-header-panel>
            </paper-drawer-panel>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "app",
                ready: function () {
                    alert('Ready!!!!');
                },
                srchandler: function () {
                    alert('Search clicked');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>
</body>
</html>
```

For completeness here is the elements.html file

```
<!-- Iron -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">

<!-- Paper Elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower-components/paper-header-panel/paper-header-panel.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-input/paper-input.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-toolbar/paper-toolbar.html">
```

I am moving to Polymer 1.0 and have just created the page above. The 'script handler called' alert is showing but the `ready` callback is not firing and when I click on the search button the `searchhandler` function is not being called.

Can anyone give me an idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html) for the migration guide. For your event not firing see [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#declarative-handlers)

> Curly brackets ({{}}) are not used for declarative event handlers in the template.

Your code should be:

```
<paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="srchandler"></paper-icon-button>
```

Your element registration needs to also now change. See [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/migration.html#registration)

```
<body unresolved class="fullbleed layout vertical">
    <dom-module id="my-app">
        <template>
        <!-- your template here -->
            <paper-drawer-panel>
                <paper-header-panel main mode="waterfall-tall">
                    <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar">
                        <paper-icon-button id="paperToggle" icon="menu" paper-drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
                        <span class="flex"></span>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="srchandler"></paper-icon-button>
                        <input type="text" id="searchText" style="width:0px;visibility:hidden;" />
                        <div class="middle paper-font-display2 app-name ident">Practice List</div>
                    </paper-toolbar>
                </paper-header-panel>
            </paper-drawer-panel>
        </template>
        <script>
            Polymer({
                is: "my-app",
                ready: function () {
                    alert('Ready!!!!');
                },
                srchandler: function () {
                    alert('Search clicked');
                }
            });
        </script>
    </dom-module>

    <my-app></my-app>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that but the event still does not fire. Mind you even if I make the code

'<paper-icon-button icon="search" on-tap="alert('Hi there');"></paper-icon-button>'

The alert does not appear either.

Comment: See the other edits I have just made to the answer. You need to change your element registration.

Comment: I've changed the code in my original question to match the changes you suggest - now instead of getting the header and drawer panel nothing is showing :( - sorry, might be missing something in the elements file but cannot think what.

Comment: See this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/temidujele/1/edit?html). The name `app` is invalid and **must** contain a dash (-). You also need to make sure you actually use your element ie. `<my-app></my-app>`. (Note this jsbin won't work and is just here to show you the code layout)

Comment: Also in your `elements.html` check you are importing the `paper-header-panel` correctly as I can see a dash rather than an underscore in the `bower_components` folder name.

Comment: Thanks All done now - at least in Chrome - now need to get it working in IE :( but I'll leave that till later - just need to get a prototype working